# Simple Join Spring Roo - Two Entities as One

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, join, spring-roo

I have two tables...

**User**

- ID
- Name
- LName

**SystemUser**

- ID
- Supervisor
- Country

They are related by ID. This is a simple join is SQL, however I am trying to join the two tables after a I reverse Engineered a Database using Spring Roo. I can't figure out the best approach to show the two tables as one entity (or at least appear that way). Any Advice?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe turning that query into a VIEW will give you what you are looking for `to show the two tables as one entity`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like SystemUser should extend User